# Is a salted password and mySQL AES_ENCRYPT sufficient for storing sensitive information?

Tags: mysql, encryption

I am using Apache, MySQL and PHP via HTTPS.

I need to be able to store sensitive information so it can be shared among several people.
If I have a database (secret) and two php files: (/var/www is my web root)

```
/var/inc.php
/var/www/secret.php
```

In /var/inc.php, among other things, I have a variable named $enckey, which is a 32 character alphanumeric string.  Its permissions are set to be read only.

In secret.php I have a username, password and key field.  They key field ($key) is a string know by all users (each person has the same key since I'm using that as part of the salt), it would be a 8-12 alphanumeric with special characters string.

Everyone has their own username and password that are MySQL users/passwords as well.  When they log in their user credentials would be validated with MySQL first.  There are no database usernames or passwords in /var/inc.php.

My secret database has a table, `secret` like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `secret` (
    `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
    `data` text,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

If I store information in a MySQL table using:

```
AES_ENCRYPT('secret data', $enckey . $key)
```

and extract the data out using

```
AES_DECRYPT(`secret`.`data`, $enckey . $key)
```

am I doing enough to keep the data stored in the MySQL `data` column safe?  Is there something more/different I should be doing?

**UPDATE**:
Any one given access to the site (anyone with a valid user name/password) would have access to all sensitive data.  The goal is to prevent a third party from getting the data if they were able to get to the database somehow.

Comment: As I read it, this is about saving sensitive DATA that needs to be read by users. The password is not encrypted, the DATA is. The whole point is -if I read this correctly - to reverse it, otherwise the data is kinda .. unusable. (ah. the comment I replied to is gone)

Comment: @Nanne Correct - we need to be able to store data and then retrieve it later.  I'm not storing a password to verify user access against.

Comment: what do you mean by "known by all users"? Every user uses the same value for `$key`?

Comment: @didierc Yes, every user would use the same value for $key - I think I have to do that so the value can be decrypted properly.

Comment: well, it really depends on how much sharing you wish to allow. If I become a user of your website, will I get to know that key? If so, it means that I get access to all the values stored in db, correct?

Comment: AES is the current standard for the secure storage of sensitive information. Provided you're using a 256 bit key, you're implementing one of the most secure algorithms in the public domain.

However, you're also using the same key to encrypt all information. That means if one tuple in your table is cracked, the whole table is cracked.

Comment: @didierc Yes, if you have access to the site you get the key and access to all information in the table.

Comment: so I suppose that the goal is to prevent non users from decrypting the db, would they manage to get a copy of it.

Comment: because, as a user, if I get a copy,I do know some of the content, I do know a significant part of the key, so I (suppose that) might be able to crack the rest.

Comment: @ChrisCooney Is there a a good way to store the sensitive data with different keys without having the users know a key for each bit of data?

Comment: @Jason The simplest method that springs to mind is to use their passwords (or a message digest of their passwords) as the key. That way, only the user with a specific password can decrypt that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A brute-force attack of AES-128 encryption is achievable, especially given the compute power of graphics cards or some of the ASIC-based systems being developed for Bitcoin mining, but still expensive for what you get.  You can make your encryption even more expensive by varying the keys (perhaps hundreds of times more expensive) or by using AES-256 (2^128 times more expensive!).

A cheaper and more likely attack is for someone to try to steal your key.  Your scenario assumes an attacker got to your database somehow.  Try and visualize the attacker's vantage point when he achieved that goal.  How well is the key protected from that vantage point?

Some examples:

- The database was acquired from a backup tape or drive.  Did you backup the key to that same tape or drive?
- The attacker somehow achieved root access to your database server.  Is that server separated from your app server that has the key?  Are there any SSH certificates that would allow access the app server from your database server?  Does your network prevent direct access from your database server to your app server?
- An attacker gains access to your source control management system.  Are any of the passwords (such as those in /var/www/secret.php) checked into source control with your application?
- You have administrators who could be coerced, tricked or bribed into providing a key.  Are you logging activity in a way that's easy to detect and difficult to cover up?  Where feasible, can you divide responsibilities such that a given admin can access either the data or the keys, but not both?
- If the laptop of one of the people with access to the app was stolen, would the attacker in possession of that laptop be able to access the database unchallenged?
- The password file is said to be read-only.  Is that read-only by the account under which the application is run and unreadable to anyone else but root?  Are there other applications sharing that account?  Are you preventing SSH access to the server using that same account?  Are the credentials of that account kept secure?

Comment: Thanks @phatfingers - After reading this I realize I do need to look into what's in source control, especially comments etc...  We are logging but not enough so we'll have to up that a bit.  Fortunately our backups are encrypted so we're decent there.